# Java: myComboBoxItemStateChanged is triggered twice?

Tags: java, swing

I've placed a JComboBox on a JDialog, then by NetBeans design view, I bind the JComboBox to an event function Events > Item > itemStateChanged

```
private void myComboBoxItemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {//created by netbeans
     System.out.println("triggered");
}
```

when I change the comboBox by `myComboBox.setSelectedIndex(#)`, it's calling the `myComboBoxItemStateChanged()` Once, but if I change it by clicking on the comboBox and selecting another item, it triggers myComboBoxItemStateChanged() twice! it prints "triggered" twice?

This issue is happening in all of my comboboxes!

What am I doing wrong? or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because one event is to tell the listener that one option has been **deselected**, and the next event to tell that another option has been **selected**.

You can figure out what an event actually refers to by calling `evt.getStateChange()`. It will return either `ItemEvent.SELECTED` or `ItemEvent.DESELECTED`.

If you change `"triggered"` to `"triggered " + evt.getStateChange()` you'd see the difference as it would print

```
triggered 2
triggered 1
```

So, if you're only interested in events where something has been *selected* you could add, to the top of your listener implementation

```
if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
    return;
```

Here's a snippet from [the docs on `getStateChange()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getStateChange%28%29):

> Returns the type of state change (selected or deselected).
>
> Returns: an integer that indicates whether the item was selected or deselected

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("triggered");
                }
        });
```

It print(triggered) once.